# Sencha Touch List doesn't get rendered in its Cordova project

Tags: cordova, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-cmd

I tested my code with "sencha web start", it works fine. I can see the images and the items in the List.

then I did the following commands:

1. sencha cordova init com.myPath.MyApp
2. sencha app run native (I have uncommented the platforms in app.json)
   When it finished all packagings and was trying to deploy the app onto simulator I stopped it and
3. cd cordova
4. cordova run wp8 --device

I can see my carousel component is working fine but the List does not even get rendered either on the device or on the "cordova serve" website.

### Update

Here is the code for the list

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'myList',

    config: {
        itemTpl: '{name}'
    },

    initialize: function (sender, eOpts) {
        this.callParent();

        var myStore = Ext.getStore("myStore");
        this.setStore(myStore);
    }
});


Ext.define('MyApp.store.MyStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'MyApp.model.MyModel',
    storeId: 'myStore',
    data: [
        { id: 1, name: 'Title 1' },
        { id: 2, name: 'Title 2' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Title 3' },
        { id: 4, name: '          ...........Expending...........' },
    ],
    autoLoad: true
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.MyModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
            { name: 'name', type: 'auto' }

        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a remote debugger to debug. See if there are any JavaScript errors. Inspect the DOM, it's 100% possible this is just a layout issue. By the code you provided, there isn't a way to determine this.

Comment: @MitchellSimoens Hi thank you very much for your reply. What is the remote debugger and where can I download it?